# rails tasks and generators are failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise, mongoid

I have a quite fresh Rails 6 installation, where I removed MySQL and replaced it with Mongoid.

When I try to run: `rails g devise:install`

As you can see something is using still active_record but I removed it everywhere in my code
**This is my stacktrace:**

```
/Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:240:in `database_configuration': Cannot load database configuration:
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"] (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:72:in `class_eval'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:72:in `block in execute_hook'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:327:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.2.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.2.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:370:in `active_record_configured?'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:287:in `disconnect_database'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:111:in `preload'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

**How can I overcome this issue?**

(I also deleted everything in `/tmp/cache`)

This is the beginning of my `application.rb`:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_storage/engine"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_mailbox/engine"
require "action_text/engine"
# require "action_view/railtie"
# require "action_cable/engine"
# require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

Comment: I saw, that there is an issue with Spring: https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/601

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure devise to work with mongoid instead of ActiveRecord.

Add this

```
require 'devise/orm/mongoid'
```

to `devise.rb` initializer.

For more info check [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#other-orms) and [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/orm/mongoid.rb)

Comment: I think it has something to do with spring or bootsnap. When I prefix my rails tasks and generators with `DISABLE_SPRING=1` it works, but that should not be normal. I've never had to do this in one of my projects

Comment: I also added content of my application.rb

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Spring/Rails 6. See https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/601.

Workarounds are:

1. removing Spring from your application;
2. providing a full ActiveRecord configuration, for example using sqlite.

This issue only happens in development - you don't need a production AR configuration because spring shouldn't be loaded in production.